# Automatically opening a menu item

Tags: jquery, triggers

I'm a coding novice and am learning as I go, I'm stuck at something out of my depth.

I have a wordpress site, and a plugin to create a mega menu, so none of this is made from scratch. I want to try and have a submenu item open by default when the sidemenu is opened. I'm trying to write a jQuery function to click on the submenu item that is triggered by opening the menu.

The menu button doesn't have an ID, only a class which seems unique to the button. Here's what I've got so far but neither are working.

```
$(".responsive-menu-toggle").click(function(){
    var elem = $("#mega-menu-item-4080");
elem.addClass("mega-toggle-on");
});
```

I've also tried

```
(".responsive-menu-toggle").click(function() {
openSubMenu;
});


function openSubMenu(){
var elem = $("#mega-menu-item-4080").trigger("click");
};
```

Any help as to where I'm going wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks ok - the problem is likely that some existing scripts are overriding it (for ex, not allowing click events on menu items while the menu is animating, etc). Do you know what plugin (etc) is used to power your menu? If so, it may have ways built in to get the submenu you want open by default, just by adding an html `data` attribute or something.

Comment: Thank you - yes a plugin is configuring the menu, and the icon comes from the theme. There's no option in the settings but maybe I can add some custom code to the plugin, good suggestion.
For clarification, are both of those functions I wrote ok? Is there one to focus on over the other?

Comment: Either may work... you can actually test both in the dev console. I would open your dev tools and try each of these: `$("#mega-menu-item-4080").addClass("mega-toggle-on")` and `$("#mega-menu-item-4080").click()`. The second one may have a better chance of working with a plugin. I suspect the reason it is not working as you've tried it has to do with timing (the larger menu is mid-open), but try it from your console.

Comment: Hmm, tried it out and the first one works, but only sometimes and I'm not sure why. When it does work I see this 

`a.fn.init [li#mega-menu-item-4080.mega-menu-item.mega-menu-item-type-post_type.mega-menu-item-object-page.mega-…, context: document, selector: "#mega-menu-item-4080"]`
and when it doesn't I see this 
`a.fn.init [context: document, selector: "#mega-menu-item-4080"]`

Answer (score 0):

You left out the braces that actually call the function.

Replace

```
openSubMenu;
```

with:

```
openSubMenu();
```

Comment: @Teague you mention that the element has a class name but your selector is targeting an ID... could that be it

Comment: The menu item I want to open has an ID (#mega-menu-item-4080), but the menu icon has no ID, only a class, and it being a WP installation and prebuilt theme I'm not sure if / how I can add an ID to the button